# What do the different dates mean in XML returned by IBM Connections 4.0?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

The XML returned from direct REST calls to Connections 4.0 returns dates like so, from a File:

```
<published>2013-08-06T15:00:08.390Z</published>
<updated>2013-08-15T15:30:20.367Z</updated>
<td:created>2013-08-06T15:00:08.390Z</td:created>
<td:modified>2013-08-15T13:16:59.151Z</td:modified>
<td:lastAccessed></td:lastAccessed>
```

and from a File Comment:

```
<published>2013-08-08T18:04:44.949Z</published>
<updated>2013-08-08T18:05:39.566Z</updated>
<td:modified xmlns:td="urn:ibm.com/td">2013-08-08T18:05:39.566Z</td:modified>
<td:created xmlns:td="urn:ibm.com/td">2013-08-08T18:04:44.949Z</td:created>
```

The API documentation is vague about the conditions under which these dates are set:

```
<td:created>   Creation timestamp in Atom format.
<td:modified>  The date that the comment was last updated. Timestamp in Atom format.
<updated>      The date that the comment was last updated, as defined in the Atom specification.
<published>    The date the comment was initially published, as defined in the Atom specification.
```

Can one assume that `<published>` == `<td:created>` and that `<updated>` == `<td:modified>`, as the data seems to indicate, or are there circumstances under which these dates would have different values? Does the answer to this question vary by application (Files, Blogs, etc.)?

#### Edit

`<updated>` and `<published>` are Atom-defined properties. The `<td:...>` ones are IBM's extensions.

Another way to ask my question might be, What descriptions or definitions would I use to explain each of these dates to a user?

Comment: it's a syndication format, I imagine. it would take major effect when  you are aggregating entries.

Comment: Add some clarification in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst `td:created` and `published` are generally identical, with the foremost exception of content created as a draft and later published, applications use `td:modified` and `updated` with slightly different semantics. In Wikis for instance `updated` reflects the time page *contents or metadata* last changed, while `td:modified` is only updated when *page contents* i.e. title or text are updated. I expect the [API documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation) to clarify these subtle details, if not please post comments and ask for improvements.